# How to attach things to cinder block walls? (For training wisteria plant)

Tags: vines, branches, trellis, wall, wisteria

I have a wisteria plant that I would like to train into long, horizontal branches. It's growing against a cinder block wall. I tried screwing some masonry screws into it, but those just ground a hole in the wall that was too big for the screw to then grab anything.

How can I attach things to cinder block walls? Do I need to use some kind of epoxy instead of screws? And then what kind of anchor/device should I then attach that will be good for supporting the wisteria branches?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can glue (2-part epoxy, jbweld, gorilla glue, etc) the masonry screw into the holes you made. Gorrila glue would be a good fit as it foams and expands while curing, locking it into place against the odd-shaped hole and post.

Comment: Suggestion: Before you apply any method, get yourself a single block of the same type and try it on that block. If it destroys that block you don't want to use it on the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Get plastic inserts at any hardware store. Drill a hole ,push in insert, thread in screw. The inset package will specify drill and screw sizes. I strongly recommend drilling holes in the mortor.

Answer (score 1):

Wisteria is usually a strong climber and can easily put a lot of weight on a support.

There are at least two ways to do this:

- buy or build a trellis.  Be sure it's installed firmly in the ground.  You could pound 6' T Bars into the ground and attach the trellis to that or pour concrete into a post hole and attach the feet of the trellis to that.
- use a product like [this](https://espalar.com/) but you end up drilling holes in your cinder block for the attachment points